# Bootable media not working

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, bootable-media

So i have Ubuntu installed in my system. I formatted the 8GB usb stick (mbr partition) **created a FAT32 partition** and copied contents of ISO.

After sometime i notice error in copying because install.wim is greater than 4 gb, Then too i booted from USB. The installer was working but it gave me(shoud give) an error.

So i formatted the drive again **changed the filesystem to NTFS and now it is not booting**.

To check that bootable USB is working correctly I booted it in my other system and it worked properly.

But not working in my current system(Lenovo yoga 500).

Comment: You shouldn't simply copy the ISO file to the existing filesystem of the flash drive. You should overwrite the entire contents of the flash drive bit-by-bit with the contents of the ISO file. There are specialized utilities for doing so. Since you're on Ubuntu, I recommend `dd`.

Comment: I use this utility to copy Windows images to a usb drive>>>>https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56485

Comment: Sorry my bad, i didn't simple copies the iso i copied it's content @hedgie

Comment: And i have Ubuntu so i think this tool won't work in my system @Moab